# How to create table with simple border in HTML 5

Tags: html, css

What is the easiest way to get such table as bellow in `HTML 5`. I have a feeling that my solution (with setting style for every `td`) is not the best way.

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid;">1</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid;">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid;">3</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid;">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I hoped that there is something like border attribute in html 4. But us I see I need to use CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is best accomplished by using an internal CSS stylesheet, rather than using inline styles on your table elements. Following is an example of how you can use a CSS stylesheet to style your table.

First, give the table an `id` like this:

```
<table id="thetable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then use CSS on the table:

```
#thetable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#thetable td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

The entire HTML document would look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Table Page</title>
    <style>
    #thetable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid;
    }

    #thetable td {
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="thetable" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.ipl.org/div/kidsweb/tags12c.html) on how to get the CSS into your HTML using a stylesheet. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS classes.

```css
table.MyClass {
    /* Whatever table styles here */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid;
}
table.MyClass td {
    /* Whatever cell styles within the table here */
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="MyClass">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Externalise the CSS to a separate stylesheet.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```